# How to process large file with one record dependent on another in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a scenario where there is a really large file and say line 1 record might have dependency on 1000th line data and the line 1 and 1000 can be part of separate spilts. Now my understanding of the framework is that record reader is going to return one key, value pair to mapper and each k,v pair will be independent of another. Moreover since the file has been divided into splits and i want that as well (i.e. splittable false is no option), can i handle this anyhow may be writing my own record reader, mapper or reducer?

Dependency is like -

Row1: a,b,c,d,e,f

Row2: x,y,z,p,q,r

Now x in Row2 need to be used with say d in Row1 to get my desired output.

Thanks.

Comment: how is the dependency defined?(having same key or in what means)?

Comment: Updated the Question...

Comment: I don't see an option other than sending out the values which has some sort of dependency(x and d) to the same reducer by having a custom partitioner and carrying out the actual calculation in the reducer provided if the dependency is easy to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to implement a **reducer side join**. Here you can see a better explanation of it: http://hadooped.blogspot.mx/2013/09/reduce-side-joins-in-java-map-reduce.html.

Both related values have to end in the same reducer (defined by the key and the **Partitioner**) and they should be grouped together (**GroupingComparator**) and may be use a **SecondSort** to order the grouped values.